# Why using goto is regarded as bad practice, but call/cc isn't?

Tags: functional-programming, goto, control-flow, callcc

I am currently learning the concept of **continuations**. I am struggling with understanding why direct control flow manipulation by e.g. **goto** command is a bad practice, but doing so using **call/cc** is just fine. Isn't it the same thing, but achieved by different means?

**Why using goto is regarded as a bad practice, but using call/cc is not?**

Comment: It is: [An argument against call/cc](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/against-callcc.html)

Comment: Delimited (or composable) continuations are a viable alternative with some desirable traits: [Delimited Continuations for Everyone by Kenichi Asai](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNM-njddhIw)

Comment: @bob Oleg Kiselyov article is actually the reason why I asked this question. My reasoning was that if he wrote the article then it must stand in opposition to wide usage of call/cc (therefor not regarded as bad).

Comment: Good point. So the question is how many languages actually implement `call/cc` as a core language feature. I think `call/cc` was rather an academic debate and an object of research.. People have barely used it, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if one can say that call/cc was only academic concept. According to wikipedia it is implemented in few quite notable languages (e.g. C++, Ruby):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation#Languages_implementing_call/cc
If it is actually widely used in people's projects? I'm not sure about that.